# Marco loop value and do math

Tags: vba, excel, math

Below code is able to split "comma" into separated value, but i am facing another question. When the value with *1,*2,*3,etc...How can I Multiply it?

As you can see, if the row has "need follow-up", means can't lookup from image2 value. Because the value with *1/*2/etc...

so my question is, how can i make it like if the image1 2b*1 = 18 and if 2b*2 = 36.

Image1

[image]

Image2

[image]

```
   For b = 8 To .Cells(8, "D").End(xlDown).Row
        ttl = 0
        ttlerror = ""
        vals = Split(.Cells(b, "D").Value2, Chr(44))
        For a = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
            pc = Application.Match(vals(a), sh.Columns(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(pc) Then
                ttl = ttl + sh.Cells(pc, "B").Value2
            ElseIf IsError(pc) Then
                ttlerror = "Need follow-up"
                ttlerrrorcount = ttlerrrorcount + 1
            End If
        Next a
        .Cells(b, "F") = ttl
        .Cells(b, "G") = ttlerror
    Next b
```

Comment: what programming language is it?

Comment: Even after stating the programming language, I think you still need to explain the meaning of "to split", "comma", "into separated value" (in contrast to valueS, plural). In short, your question needs a lot of explanation to become clear.

Comment: VBA excel......

Comment: Could you be more specific on what are you trying to accomplish and what have you tried until now? Your code does anything of what you want to accomplish (b=9???)